# Lua variable scope, function forward declaration and refactoring a Lua script by using the 'require' statement

Tags: c++, c, lua

I am finding Lua's scoping rules a bit confusing. I have submitted below, a snippet of a Lua script to highlight the issues I want to ask question(s) about:

```
-- 'forward definitions'
-- could these be moved to the bottom of the script to 'tidy up' the script?
-- could these reside in another file imported by require 'filename' to tidy up the script even more?

[[ Note: This function is accessing variables defined later on/elsewhere in the script
         and is also setting a variable (flag) which is then used elsewhere in the script
]]

function war_is_needed()
    if (goodwill:extendsToAllMen() and peace) then
        if player:isAppointedLeader() then
           economy_is_booming = false
           return true
        else
           economy_is_booming = nil
           return true
        end           
    else
        economy_is_booming = nil
        return false
    end
end



world = WorldFactory:new('rock#3')
player = PlayerFactory:getUser('barney', world)

while (not player:isDead()) do
    peace = world:hasPeace()
    goodwill = world:getGoodwillInfo()

    if war_is_needed() then
       world:goToWar()
    else
       if (not economy_is_booming) then
           player:setNervousState(true)
           player:tryToStartAWar()
       else
           player:setNervousState(false)
           player:liveFrivously()
       end if
    end   
end
```

My questions are (Ignoring for now that global variables CAN be considered evil) :

- Could the function at the top of the script be moved to the bottom of the script to 'tidy up' the script?
- Could the function at the top of the script be refactored (i.e. moved) into a separate file 'warfuncs.lua' and then imported into the script by replacing the function definition with a  require 'warfuncs.lua'?

Whilst answering the above two questions, please bear in mind that the function at the top of the script is accessing variables defined later on/elsewhere in the script
and is also setting a variable (flag) which is then used elsewhere in the script.

Do the scoping rules change if Lua is embedded in C or C++ (where objects may be being created on the heap)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lhf is correct, you can refactor your code and it will still work. Keep in mind, though, that while everything in this particular example script is global, it is often a good idea, if working with variables that are effectively temporary (say, within the scope of a loop or single function), to declare them as `local`.

In regards to the third question about embedding in C/C++, there is no difference in scope rules within the Lua script, as the application would create a single Lua state, and load your script files. Any files that perform a require do so within the scope of the state they were loaded into during the C/C++ application initialization.

Answer (score 2):

`war_is_needed` cannot be moved after the while loop. If the while loop were contained in a function, then `war_is_needed` could be moved after it. Since everything is global, the answer to the second question is yes.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you just have to make sure that you define your functions/variables/ ... before using them, so there this snippet won't give problems

```
function foo()
    print(a)
end
a="Bar!"
foo()
```

But this will:

```
a="Bar!"
foo()
function foo()
    print(a)
end
```

So everything needs to be defined before the function is run, and effectively uses variables. Whether you define them in the main script or dofile/require them doesn't matter.